# How to get rid of GTK4: warning: "Gtk-WARNING: GtkGizmo (slider) reported min height -2, but sizes must be >= 0"

Tags: gtk, gtk4

I'm not using any object called a slider so I'm guessing that's generic term for something that can be adjusted in size manually, probably the **"GtkPaned"** object since you can grab it and slide it.

I've looked on the net and found some discussions about the properly **min-width** and **min-height** seemingly related to this warning but adding a property tag like **<property name="min-*" ...>** just gives me a property unknown error no matter what I add it to. I haven't tried it in CSS yet mainly because I'm brand new to GTK and my reading so far has suggested that CSS is something you can add for styling but don't actually need.

I've tried adding **height/width-request** on various widgets and that didn't help.

Here's what happens, in the code below if I use `gtk4-builder-tool validate file.ui` on it I get no errors.

If I look at it with `gtk4-builder-tool preview file.ui &` then I get these errors on startup

```
Gtk-WARNING: GtkGizmo (slider) reported min width  -2, but sizes must be >= 0
Gtk-WARNING: GtkGizmo (slider) reported min height -2, but sizes must be >= 0
```

If I open up the menu and move around it I get these errors on the menu events:

```
Gtk-WARNING: GtkGizmo (slider) reported min width  -2, but sizes must be >= 0
Gtk-WARNING: GtkGizmo (slider) reported min height -2, but sizes must be >= 0
```

so the same however even without a menu in the file I get the first two errors when the file is **previewed**.

I'm sure if I wasn't so new at GTK I would know how to identify the object and fix this but right now I'm a little green.

The menu is just something generic I found and used to learn how to put one in a **.ui** file so I don't mind if it's not complete.

```xml
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<!-- Created with Cambalache 0.16.0 -->
<interface>
  <!-- interface-name file.ui -->
  <!-- interface-authors Reg Proctor -->
  <requires lib="gio" version="2.0"/>
  <requires lib="gtk" version="4.6"/>
  <object class="GtkApplicationWindow" id="appWin">
    <property name="default-height">925</property>
    <property name="default-width">1200</property>
    <property name="title">Settings</property>
    <child>
      <object class="GtkBox" id="main_box">
        <property name="orientation">GTK_ORIENTATION_VERTICAL</property>
        <child>
          <object class="GtkPopoverMenuBar">
            <property name="halign">start</property>
            <property name="margin-bottom">10</property>
            <property name="menu-model">menu</property>
            <property name="name">General Menu</property>
            <property name="valign">start</property>
          </object>
        </child>
        <child>
          <object class="GtkPaned">
            <child>
              <object class="GtkFrame">
                <property name="label">Settings</property>
                <child>
                  <object class="GtkStackSidebar">
                    <property name="halign">start</property>
                    <property name="height-request">900</property>
                    <property name="stack">pages</property>
                    <property name="valign">start</property>
                  </object>
                </child>
              </object>
            </child>
            <child>
              <object class="GtkFrame">
                <child>
                  <object class="GtkStack" id="pages">
                    <property name="name">Timezone</property>
                    <child>
                      <object class="GtkStackPage" id="GeneralSetup">
                        <property name="child">
                          <object class="GtkFlowBox">
                            <property name="margin-bottom">20</property>
                            <property name="margin-end">50</property>
                            <property name="margin-start">50</property>
                            <property name="margin-top">20</property>
                            <property name="name">Timezone</property>
                            <child>
                              <object class="GtkEntry" id="GeneralSetup.Timezone">
                                <property name="activates-default">True</property>
                                <property name="halign">start</property>
                                <property name="height-request">10</property>
                                <property name="input-purpose">alpha</property>
                                <property name="placeholder-text">Timezone</property>
                                <property name="text">America/Phoenix</property>
                                <property name="tooltip-text">Enter your timezone</property>
                                <property name="valign">center</property>
                                <property name="width-request">50</property>
                              </object>
                            </child>
                          </object>
                        </property>
                        <property name="name">General Setup</property>
                        <property name="title">General Setup</property>
                      </object>
                    </child>
                  </object>
                </child>
              </object>
            </child>
          </object>
        </child>
      </object>
    </child>
  </object>
  <menu id="menu">
    <submenu>
      <attribute name="label">File</attribute>
      <section>
        <item>
          <attribute name="action">app.new</attribute>
          <attribute name="label">New</attribute>
        </item>
        <item>
          <attribute name="action">app.quit</attribute>
          <attribute name="label">Quit</attribute>
        </item>
      </section>
    </submenu>
    <submenu>
      <attribute name="label">Edit</attribute>
      <section>
        <item>
          <attribute name="action">win.copy</attribute>
          <attribute name="label">Copy</attribute>
        </item>
        <item>
          <attribute name="action">win.paste</attribute>
          <attribute name="label">Paste</attribute>
        </item>
      </section>
    </submenu>
    <submenu>
      <attribute name="label">Choices</attribute>
      <submenu>
        <attribute name="label">Shapes</attribute>
        <section>
          <item>
            <attribute name="action">win.shape</attribute>
            <attribute name="label">Line</attribute>
            <attribute name="target">line</attribute>
          </item>
          <item>
            <attribute name="action">win.shape</attribute>
            <attribute name="label">Triangle</attribute>
            <attribute name="target">triangle</attribute>
          </item>
          <item>
            <attribute name="action">win.shape</attribute>
            <attribute name="label">Square</attribute>
            <attribute name="target">square</attribute>
          </item>
          <item>
            <attribute name="action">win.shape</attribute>
            <attribute name="label">Polygon</attribute>
            <attribute name="target">polygon</attribute>
          </item>
          <item>
            <attribute name="action">win.shape</attribute>
            <attribute name="label">Circle</attribute>
            <attribute name="target">circle</attribute>
          </item>
        </section>
      </submenu>
      <section>
        <item>
          <attribute name="action">app.state</attribute>
          <attribute name="label">On</attribute>
          <attribute name="target">on</attribute>
        </item>
        <item>
          <attribute name="action">app.state</attribute>
          <attribute name="label">Off</attribute>
          <attribute name="target">off</attribute>
        </item>
      </section>
      <section>
        <item>
          <attribute name="action">app.awesome</attribute>
          <attribute name="label">Awesome</attribute>
        </item>
      </section>
    </submenu>
    <submenu>
      <attribute name="label">Help</attribute>
      <section>
        <item>
          <attribute name="action">win.about</attribute>
          <attribute name="label">About</attribute>
        </item>
      </section>
    </submenu>
  </menu>
</interface>
```